# Java: Infinite Loop Convention

Tags: java, infinite-loop, conventions

What is the convention for an infinite loop in Java? Should I write `while(true)` or `for(;;)`? I personally would use `while(true)` because I use while loops less often.

Comment: I would rather do `while(running)`, so I have a way out of it.

Answer (score 84, accepted):

There is no difference in bytecode between `while(true)` and `for(;;)` but I prefer `while(true)` since it is less confusing (especially for someone new to Java).

You can check it with this code example

```
void test1(){
    for (;;){
        System.out.println("hello");
    }
}
void test2(){
    while(true){
        System.out.println("world");
    }
}
```

When you use command `javap -c ClassWithThoseMethods` you will get

```
  void test1();
    Code:
       0: getstatic     #15                 // Field java/lang/System.out:Ljava/io/PrintStream;
       3: ldc           #21                 // String hello
       5: invokevirtual #23                 // Method java/io/PrintStream.println:(Ljava/lang/String;)V
       8: goto          0

  void test2();
    Code:
       0: getstatic     #15                 // Field java/lang/System.out:Ljava/io/PrintStream;
       3: ldc           #31                 // String world
       5: invokevirtual #23                 // Method java/io/PrintStream.println:(Ljava/lang/String;)V
       8: goto          0
```

which shows same structure (except "hello" vs "world" strings) .

Comment: I think it's time for Java to come up with an infinite loop construction so we don't need workarounds, like other languages have. May I suggest `do {}` without `while` being required, or simply `loop {}`.

Comment: @OliverHausler I'd prefer `forever`, like e.g. in Scratch https://wiki.scratch.mit.edu/wiki/Forever_%28block%29

Answer (score 15):

I prefer `while(true)`, because I use while loops less often than for loops. For loops have better uses and `while(true)` is much cleaner and easy to read than `for(;;)`

Comment: Another argument in favor of while( true ) is maintainability: true may become a logic condition in the future

Comment: @Aubin OTOH, `for(;;)` is more pleasant when golfing

Comment: @Aubin, so can the middle part of the `for`! Just stick it in like `for(; condition(););`. Using a `for` also means you could easily add a variable to count iterations of the loop (or other 'between iterations' stuff) after the second of the two semicola.

Comment: There's nothing "hard to read" about `for...` its a three letter word.

Answer (score 9):

It's up to you. I don't think there is a convention for such a thing. You can either use `while(true)` or `for(;;)`

I would say I encounter more often `while(true)` in the source codes. `for(;;)` is less often used and harder to read.

Comment: Another argument in favor of while( true ) is maintainability: true may become a logic condition in the future

Comment: There's nothing "hard to read" about `for...` its a three letter word.

Answer (score 6):

`for(;;)` sucks, it is completely unintuitive to read for rookies. Please use `while(true)` instead.

Answer (score 5):

Ultimately, it is your choice. The Java tutorials show both [for](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/for.html) and [while](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/while.html).

However, `while(true)` is used more often as it's far more understandable.