# What is the condition for this "for(;;)" loop?

Tags: java, for-loop, conditional-statements

Can someone explain what is the condition for this for loop?

```
for(;;) {
 //do sth.
}
```

Comment: Same as `while(true)`

Comment: related: [java-infinite-loop-convention](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15989618/java-infinite-loop-convention)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It has no condition. It's an infinite loop.

Answer (score 2):

If the test condition is empty (and it is here), there is no test and the loop continues indefinitely. It's a short form for an infinite loop.

Answer (score 2):

It is an infinite loop as the condition is empty.

From the java [specs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.14.1.1) If the Expression is not present, then the only way a for statement can complete normally is by use of a `break` statement. As you don't have condition and `break` so your its an infinite loop.

Answer (score 2):

This is an infinite for loop with no condition. The for loop contains following semantics

```
for(loop variable initialization ; condition to terminate ; variable increment)
```

Since there is nothing in between then two ';'its no condition infinite loop

Answer (score 2):

It is equal to this:

```
while(true){
 //do sth.
}
```

which is an infinite loop.

Answer (score 2):

If you tries to decompile this simple program

```
for(;;){
    System.out.println("yes");
}
```

You will get this one as result:

```
do
   System.out.println("yes");
while(true);
```

I'm using this decompile tool: [JAD Java Decompiler](http://varaneckas.com/jad/) (dont work for Java 8+)

Answer (score 1):

The three expressions of the for loop are optional, an infinite loop can be created as follows:

```
// Infinite loop
for ( ; ; ) {
   // Your code goes here
}
```

Answer (score 1):

As everyone said, it is an infinite loop. A simple way to see that it is an infinite loop is to look the `for(;;)` statement in byte code.

Take this reference class:

```
public class Test {
    public static void main (String[] args){
        for(;;){}
    }
}
```

The compiler output (in bytecode):

```
public class Test {
  public Test();
    Code:
       0: aload_0       
       1: invokespecial #1                  // Method java/lang/Object."<init>":()V
       4: return        

  public static void main(java.lang.String[]);
    Code:
       0:
         goto 0
}
```

The `goto 0` jumps at the label `0`, which is above line. This process will never stops.