# Why can't you place a print statement after a for loop with no parameters?

Tags: java, loops, for-loop, printing

Why can't you place a print statement after this type of for loop? I don't understand what's going on. I understand this is not the standard way to write a for loop. So I was experimenting with this code because I saw this code somewhere. I just don't understand why you can't place the print statement at the end.

public class Test{

```
public static void main(String [] args){    
    for( ; ; ) {
        int x = 0;
        if (x < 5) {
            System.out.print(x + " ");
            x++;
        }
    }
    System.out.println("The End"); //This line will not compile.
}
```

}

Comment: And the compiler will tell you this -- that you've got unreachable code. Lesson: read critically and believe the compiler error messages.

Answer (score 1):

[`for( ; ; )` is same as `while(true)`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15989618/java-infinite-loop-convention/15989663#15989663) and since you are not breaking this loop anywhere you created infinite loop.

So any code placed after such loop will never be executed (will be unreachable/dead code) and compiler informs you about this problem since such situation most probably wasn't your intention.

Answer (score 0):

The loop never ends. You need to break it somewhere. Its like a while(true) like this. You can refactor a `for(pre, cond, after){code}` do a while

```
pre
while(cond)
{
    code
    after
}
```

so if you do `for (;;)` it's basically like a `while(true)`.