# Print below series in single loop and using single variable only

Tags: java, arrays, for-loop, data-structures

I'm trying to print the following sequence infinitely:

```
0   100
1    99
2    98
.     .
.     .
.     .
97    3 
98    2
99    1
100   0 
99    1
98    2
97    3
.     .
.     .
.     . 
3     97
2     98
1     99
0     100
.      .
.      .
.      .
```

However, when I run this, the pattern only prints once.

Here's my code:

```
public class PrintSequence {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        int i=0;
        while(true) 
        {
            if(i<=100) {
                System.out.println(i+ "   " + (100-i));    
                i++;
            }

        }

    }
}
```

The assignment only allows me to use a single loop and a single variable.

Comment: Please improve your question: show us what you've tried and use it to help ask a more specific and higher quality question. Please check out the [ask] and the [help] for more on best practices for this site.

Comment: `void print_number(void) {for (int i = 0; i == 0; ++i) {puts("0 100 1 99 2 98 . . . . . . 97 3 98 2 99 1 100 0 99 1 98 2 97 3 . . . . . . 3 97 2 98 1 99 0 100 1 99 2 98 3 97 . . . . . .");}}` Not helpful, but you haven't shown an attempt, and it technically fulfills what you've asked.

Comment: Sorry for the typo @Hovercraft . I have made correction.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels .I have added my code as well. pls check

Comment: Out of curiosity, why did you tag the C language? This doesn't appear to be related to that topic in the least.

Comment: @EJoshuaS-ReinstateMonica Because it can be solved using any language.

Comment: @ayazhusain That doesn't mean that you should tag it in the language you're not using. Only tag a question with more than one language if it has something to do with interoperability between those two languages.

Comment: BTW the problem is that once you reach `i == 100` there's no way to reset `i` to 0, so the loop will keep going but it'll never print anything. Add `else { i = 0; }` and this'll work.

Comment: @EJoshuaS-ReinstateMonica thanks for editing and making it more readable.

Comment: No problem, glad I could help.

Comment: @EJoshuaS-ReinstateMonica , it won't work, it should be printed in reverse order.

Comment: Sorry, I missed that - so you want it to reverse every time? Yeah, I see that now that I look at the expected output again. You could add a Boolean variable indicating what direction you were printing and switch the direction in the `else` statement.

Comment: @EJoshuaS-ReinstateMonica I can use  single loop and single variable only.

Comment: In that case, just as a hint in the right direction: there's a solution using modular arithmetic.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels pls mark this question as open, it has complete and precise information now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are 2 tricks needed to solve this:

- Realize that a full cycle from `0,100` back to `0,100` is 200 iterations, then use `%` remainder operator to write an infinite loop within range 0-199.
- Use [`Math.abs()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/13/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Math.html#abs(int))<sup>1</sup> to turn a negative number into a positive number.

Here is 2 lines of code that will produce the desired infinite output:

```
for (int i = 0; ; i = (i + 1) % 200)
    System.out.printf("%-6d%d%n", 100 - Math.abs(100 - i), Math.abs(100 - i));
```

---

*Explanation*

`for (;;)` is a loop that runs "forever" ([infinitely](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15989618/5221149)). It is the same as `for (; true; )`, and the same as `while (true)`, but using `for` allows keeping `int i = 0`, the loop, and `i = (i + 1) % 200` together in one line of code.

`i = (i + 1) % 200` means that when `i = 199`, the next value is `i = 0`, starting the sequence all over again, forever iterating through values 0..199.

`100 - i` makes the sequence 0..199 become 100..-99.

`Math.abs(100 - i)` makes the sequence become 100..0..99, i.e. the second column of the output.

`100 - Math.abs(100 - i)` makes the sequence become 0..100..1, i.e. the first column of the output.

`printf("%-6d%d%n", ...)` makes it print nice in 2 columns.

---

<sup>*1) If `Math.abs()` is not allowed, use a `?:` ternary conditional operator instead:

`printf("%-6d%d%n", (i < 100 ? i : 200 - i), (i < 100 ? 100 - i : i - 100))`*</sup>

Answer (score 1):

You can do it as follows:

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int i = 0;
        while (true) {
            if (i <= 100) {
                System.out.println(i + "\t" + (100 - i));
                i++;
            } else if (i <= 200) {
                System.out.println((200 - i) + "\t" + (i - 100));
                i++;
            }
            if (i == 200) {
                i = 0;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Salient features:**

1. It exactly meets your requirement.
2. It does not require any library.